# Active Directory/DNS problem

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

I've been having some issues with our local domain name resolving for some reason. A short description of my entire network is: We have two offices. Each office has its own DC and its own firewall, but both offices are replicated with each other. Now, one of the office networks is working just fine, the one I'm having problems with is the one I'm currently on.

As an example, I can access \\server1\myshare  but I cannot access \\mydomain.net\myshare on my current network. On the other network everything is working ok. Now, at random intervals when I'm in RDP on server1 I CAN access the domain, but other times I cannot. I believe I've tracked down the culprit but I'm not even sure how to begin fixing this problem. Here is the dcdiag output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Ldap search capabality attribute search failed on server BGS-CP-VRDSVR01,
   return value = 81
   Got error while checking if the DC is using FRS or DFSR. Error:
   Win32 Error 81The VerifyReferences, FrsEvent and DfsrEvent tests might fail
   because of this error.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: BGS-HQ\BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
      Starting test: Connectivity
         The host 6282bfca-ade1-41c8-84dc-516ce19b49be._msdcs.billsgs.net could
         not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP, server
         name, etc.
         Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your
         firewall settings.
         ......................... BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01 failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: BGS-HQ\BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
      Skipping all tests, because server BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01 is not responding to
```

Now.. the fun part about this is, I ran the following:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup 6282bfca-ade1-41c8-84dc-516ce19b49be._msdcs.bill
sgs.net
Server:  bgs-hq-vrdsvr01.billsgs.net
Address:  192.168.40.13

Name:    bgs-hq-vrdsvr01.billsgs.net
Address:  192.168.40.13
Aliases:  6282bfca-ade1-41c8-84dc-516ce19b49be._msdcs.billsgs.net
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm a programmer, not a network administrator so I certainly don't know a lot of debugging techniques with this, and especially windows server.

Also, as a side note, we have disabled the replication server for the time being because for some reason it is literally using all of the 12gb of RAM on the server. I'm not sure if this is related but as of right now it's on the back burner.

EDIT: I apologize, we are running Windows Server 2008 R2 and below is an ipconfig /all from the server.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : billsgs.net
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : billsgs.net

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-03-BA-38
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.13(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.13
                                       192.168.40.254
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.13
   Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 192.168.41.17
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{ADEC15A8-2603-40EB-964C-489CCBD11E08}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

EDIT: Here is the output of a DNS test I ran.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dcdiag /test:DNS

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Ldap search capabality attribute search failed on server BGS-CP-VRDSVR01, return value = 81
   Got error while checking if the DC is using FRS or DFSR. Error: Win32 Error 81The VerifyReferences, FrsEvent and DfsrEvent tests might fail because of this error.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: BGS-HQ\BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
      Starting test: Connectivity
         The host 6282bfca-ade1-41c8-84dc-516ce19b49be._msdcs.billsgs.net could not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP, server name, etc.
         Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your firewall settings.
         ......................... BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01 failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: BGS-HQ\BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01

      Starting test: DNS

         DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...
         ......................... BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01 passed test DNS

   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : Schema

   Running partition tests on : Configuration

   Running partition tests on : billsgs

   Running enterprise tests on : billsgs.net
      Starting test: DNS
         Test results for domain controllers:

            DC: BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01.billsgs.net
            Domain: billsgs.net


               TEST: Basic (Basc)
                  Error: No LDAP connectivity
                  Warning: adapter [00000007] Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection has invalid DNS server: 192.168.40.254 (<name unavailable>)
                  No host records (A or AAAA) were found for this DC

               TEST: Forwarders/Root hints (Forw)
                  Error: All forwarders in the forwarder list are invalid.
                  Error: Both root hints and forwarders are not configured or broken. Please make sure at least one of them works.

               TEST: Delegations (Del)
                  Error: DNS server: bgs-cp-vrdsvr01.billsgs.net. IP:192.168.41.17 [Broken delegated domain _msdcs.billsgs.net.]
                  Error: DNS server: bgs-cp-vrdsvr01.billsgs.net. IP:192.168.41.17 [Broken delegated domain cp.billsgs.net.]

               TEST: Dynamic update (Dyn)
                  Warning: Failed to add the test record dcdiag-test-record in zone billsgs.net

               TEST: Records registration (RReg)
                  Network Adapter [00000007] Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection:
                     Warning:
                     Missing CNAME record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     6282bfca-ade1-41c8-84dc-516ce19b49be._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.22017278-29d1-493a-b72d-e44b31411a70.domains._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _kerberos._tcp.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _kerberos._udp.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _kpasswd._tcp.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.BGS-HQ._sites.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _kerberos._tcp.BGS-HQ._sites.dc._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.BGS-HQ._sites.dc._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _kerberos._tcp.BGS-HQ._sites.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _gc._tcp.BGS-HQ._sites.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.BGS-HQ._sites.gc._msdcs.billsgs.net

                     Error:
                     Missing SRV record at DNS server 192.168.40.254:
                     _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.billsgs.net

               Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network adapters

         Summary of test results for DNS servers used by the above domain controllers:

            DNS server: 192.168.41.17 (bgs-cp-vrdsvr01.billsgs.net.)
               2 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.168.41.17
            DNS server: 128.63.2.53 (h.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 128.63.2.53
            DNS server: 128.8.10.90 (d.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 128.8.10.90
            DNS server: 192.112.36.4 (g.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.112.36.4
            DNS server: 192.168.40.254 (<name unavailable>)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               Name resolution is not functional. _ldap._tcp.billsgs.net. failed on the DNS server 192.168.40.254

            DNS server: 192.203.230.10 (e.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.203.230.10
            DNS server: 192.228.79.201 (b.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.228.79.201
            DNS server: 192.33.4.12 (c.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.33.4.12
            DNS server: 192.36.148.17 (i.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.36.148.17
            DNS server: 192.5.5.241 (f.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.5.5.241
            DNS server: 192.58.128.30 (j.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 192.58.128.30
            DNS server: 193.0.14.129 (k.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 193.0.14.129
            DNS server: 198.41.0.4 (a.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 198.41.0.4
            DNS server: 199.7.83.42 (l.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 199.7.83.42
            DNS server: 202.12.27.33 (m.root-servers.net.)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 202.12.27.33
            DNS server: 209.253.113.10 (<name unavailable>)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 209.253.113.10
            DNS server: 209.253.113.2 (<name unavailable>)
               1 test failure on this DNS server
               PTR record query for the 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. failed on the DNS server 209.253.113.2
         Summary of DNS test results:

                                            Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
            _________________________________________________________________
            Domain: billsgs.net
               BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01              PASS FAIL FAIL FAIL WARN FAIL n/a

         ......................... billsgs.net failed test DNS
```

and.. the "repadmin /bind BGS-VRDSVR01" output..

```
C:\Users\Administrator.BILLSGS>repadmin /bind BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
Bind to BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01 succeeded.
NTDSAPI V1 BindState, printing extended members.
    bindAddr: BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
Extensions supported (cb=48):
    BASE                             : Yes
    ASYNCREPL                        : Yes
    REMOVEAPI                        : Yes
    MOVEREQ_V2                       : Yes
    GETCHG_COMPRESS                  : Yes
    DCINFO_V1                        : Yes
    RESTORE_USN_OPTIMIZATION         : Yes
    KCC_EXECUTE                      : Yes
    ADDENTRY_V2                      : Yes
    LINKED_VALUE_REPLICATION         : Yes
    DCINFO_V2                        : Yes
    INSTANCE_TYPE_NOT_REQ_ON_MOD     : Yes
    CRYPTO_BIND                      : Yes
    GET_REPL_INFO                    : Yes
    STRONG_ENCRYPTION                : Yes
    DCINFO_VFFFFFFFF                 : Yes
    TRANSITIVE_MEMBERSHIP            : Yes
    ADD_SID_HISTORY                  : Yes
    POST_BETA3                       : Yes
    GET_MEMBERSHIPS2                 : Yes
    GETCHGREQ_V6 (WINDOWS XP PREVIEW): Yes
    NONDOMAIN_NCS                    : Yes
    GETCHGREQ_V8 (WINDOWS XP BETA 1) : Yes
    GETCHGREPLY_V5 (WINDOWS XP BETA 2): Yes
    GETCHGREPLY_V6 (WINDOWS XP BETA 2): Yes
    ADDENTRYREPLY_V3 (WINDOWS XP BETA 3): Yes
    GETCHGREPLY_V7 (WINDOWS XP BETA 3) : Yes
    VERIFY_OBJECT (WINDOWS XP BETA 3): Yes
    XPRESS_COMPRESSION               : Yes
    DRS_EXT_ADAM                     : No
    GETCHGREQ_V10                    : Yes
    RECYCLE BIN FEATURE              : No
Site GUID: afe99967-2bae-4850-b6c8-a84fc37cbd87
Repl epoch: 0
Forest GUID: 1c4eb6fd-77b5-46de-a4b0-c9c51087eb7d
Security information on the binding is as follows:
    SPN Requested:  LDAP/BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01
    Authn Service:  9
    Authn Level:  6
    Authz Service:  0
```

Also, here is a list of processing...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p74jP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNG7j.png

Comment: Is BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01 :
1. running DNS?
2. configured to use itself as the first DNS server?

Comment: Yes, and yes. And all of the clients are using it as a name server.

Answer (score 3):

To see if this is host based firewall related, turn off the domain, public and private profiles temporarily. Do you have multiple interfaces as in Windows Server 2008 the most restrictive profile is in effect. Run this from elevated command prompt

- netsh advfirewall set publicprofile state off
- netsh advfirewall set privateprofile state off
- netsh advfirewall set domainprofile state  off

The memory usage can be misleading. Often its used but freed when necessary. Look at the resource exhaustion detector operational event log (open eventvwr and go to applications and services/microsoft/windows/resource exhaustion detector/operational) to determine if running out of memory.

Use Process Explorer to see the memory usage and see whats available. If available looks low, check with RAMMap from Syinternals to get an idea of usage. See RAMmap explained at http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx because I have had instances where metafile was "consuming" it. But it was expected behaviour.

Error 81 in DCDiag implies LDAP server was inaccessible.  Do you have any 3rd party product on the DC itself providing bundled Antivirus + Firewall behaviour? If you can access LDAP while locally on the DC but not remote and if you are sure no host based firewall is in use, I'd check if any intermediate network devices are filtering/dropping packets.

Comment: I apologize, we are running R2. \\mydomain.net\myshare is a replicated drive via the two servers. But this problem just recently started happening. NOT when we shut down the replication service a month ago. Also, when I say "access domain" I do mean, browse that share.

Comment: Firewall changes did nothing. Same error was produced.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I can connect locally AND to/from the other server remotely. And, Yes, dcdiag is being done directly on the non-working server.

Comment: Sorry for the late post. That returns the same error as above.. "The host 6282bfca-ade1-41c8-84dc-516ce19b49be._msdcs.billsgs.net could
         not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP, server
         name, etc."

Comment: I don't have any incorrect entries in the host file. In fact, we aren't even using the host file..  It's full of Microsoft comments.

Comment: I added output of a dns test to my original post as well. Also, a note about the firewall. We recently had to reinstall pfsense on our firewall, but I don't believe it is the cause of the problem, although the problem did seem to start after the new firewall was setup. With that said, I'm not blocking any ports that are related to this ( I dont think ). I have enabled port 53, which I assume in the DNS port.

Comment: Hmm the fact that you recently added port 53 to the mix makes me suspicious if the correct ports are open. do a "repadmin /bind BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01" from the other working DC and post output. This will prove if AD replication related RPC ports are accessible. I notice you point your NIC at the gateway (firewall?) as seconday DNS. Not sure how that works as it likely has no zones on itself. Is this for resolving internet names? As a test I'd configure that as a generic forwarder on BGS-HQ-VRDSVR01 DNS instead of on NIC and repeat dcdiag.

Comment: Ok, I posted the repadmin /bind output, and to the question about the firewall dns, I mentioned that we recently reinstalled the os, pfsense, on the firewall that controls that network that is not working. I still haven't found anything in the firewall that could possibly have anything to do with this issue. The other server points to its firewall has a secondary DNS, and its working correctly. The firewalls are basically setup the same with the exception of a few ports that are associated with printers, etc..

Comment: Also, I posted images of the list of processes. I really have no idea if these issues are directly related to DFS or what, but the images show you just exactly how much memory DFS is using, and thats after about 5 minutes of running. It will literally use ALL of the memory, and I'm pretty sure its not just caching. On another note.. From the "broken" server, I cannot ping the working server from the IP address or the host name "BGS-CP-VRDSVR01", but I can ping the "broken" server from the working one.

Comment: You've asked the same question again elsewhere. Do you want to discontinue this? I suggest you breakup the questions and have one for DFSR and one for your AD issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public network on any of the adapters, make sure that the main DNS server to be the "public ip of itself" that resolved the issue for me.